# How do I take the last so many entries (skip) with Eloquent Query Builder in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to write a query in Laravel using Eloquent, but only want the last 5-ongoing fields in it.  This is the query:

```
    public static function past_profile_fan_likes($id) {
        $latest_profile_fan_likes = DB::table('fanartists')
                    ->join('artists', 'fanartists.artist_id', '=', 'artists.id')
                    ->orderBy('fanartists.created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->skip(4)
                    ->where('fanartists.fan_id', '=', $id)
                    ->select('artists.id', 'artists.fbid', 'artists.stage_name', 'artists.city', 'artists.state', 'artists.image_path', 'artists.description')
                    ->get();


        return $latest_profile_fan_likes;

    }
```

When I call this, I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 4' at line 1 (SQL: select `artists`.`id`, `artists`.`fbid`, `artists`.`stage_name`, `artists`.`city`, `artists`.`state`, `artists`.`image_path`, `artists`.`description` from `fanartists` inner join `artists` on `fanartists`.`artist_id` = `artists`.`id` where `fanartists`.`fan_id` = ? order by `fanartists`.`created_at` desc offset 4) (Bindings: array ( 0 => '1', ))
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here?  Maybe something wrong with the skip usage?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `take` query in order for it to add a `LIMIT` query and turn it into the correct syntax;

```
DB::table('fanartists')
->join('artists', 'fanartists.artist_id', '=', 'artists.id')
->orderBy('fanartists.created_at', 'DESC')
->skip(4)
->take(100)
->where('fanartists.fan_id', '=', $id)
->select('artists.id', 'artists.fbid', 'artists.stage_name', 'artists.city', 'artists.state', 'artists.image_path', 'artists.description')
->get();
```

You will need to suppliy a limit if using an offset, even if you don't want to limit. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id4651990

Comment: Is there a way to supply a limit big enough that it can handle any number of entries?

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like fluent which I'm not quite as familiar with. but if you have your models and relationships defined, using Eloquent, you could reverse the order and take(5) if you're just looking to get the last 5 records:
like this...

`$latest_profile_fan_likes = fanartists::with('artists')->where('fan_id', '=', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->take(5)->get('id', 'fbid' .......);`

Comment: I don't want just the last 5 records, I want all records after the first 4.  So record 5 through however many.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Your skip() is indicated in your logic before your where().  By the error you're getting (offset),  id move it after your where clause.